# Im getting an "The default export of @sanity/client has been deprecated. Use the named export createClient instead" warning. What is the problem?

Tags: content-management-system, sanity, astrojs

I am trying to implement sanity into an existing project built with astro. I have followed this tutorial - step by step, https://www.sanity.io/guides/sanity-astro-blog

I'm not sure what the issue is but my sanity content will not render. Im getting an "The default export of @sanity/client has been deprecated. Use the named export createClient instead" warning.

In the index.astro file, I am also seeing a "Cannot find module 'astro-sanity'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option? ts(2792)" message when hovering over the useSanityClient import.

Has anyone dealt with this problem before? Thanks

Tried installing all packages in the tutorial in the frontend folder and the studio folder...

Comment: I too am starting an Astro/Sanity integration.  I did not get your error, but I've found that none of the Astro documentation matches what is actually offered by the `@sanity/astro` module.  For example, I accidentally discovered that I must use `import { useClient } from 'sanity'` followed by `await useClient.fetch(...)` to get basic operation.  None of that is in Sanity docs or sample code.  Apparently they had a big change to their library recently.